# ExceptionNSException *"Object property \'remarkTypes\' must be marked as optional." 0x000000012183e880

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm using Realm with Swift, saving data in a DB.

When saving data, I'm getting this issue:

> Object property 'remarkTypes' must be marked as optional

If I try to make `remarkTypes` optional, then it gives me this error:

> error : Generic struct 'Persisted' requires that 'List' conform to '_PersistableInsideOptional'

```swift
public class ReportRealm: Object {
    @Persisted var remarkTypes: List<RemarkTypeRealm>
}

public class RemarkTypeRealm: Object {
    @Persisted var code: String?
    @Persisted var descriptionR: String?
}
```

Comment: For readability, please [edit] your question with additional information, don’t put it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that newer versions of Swift, including SwiftUI has a `List` property which conflicts with the `List` property offered by Realm - that's a collision as the compiler doesn't know which is which.

To fix, add clarity for the compiler by telling it which List you want. In this case it's a `RealmSwift.List`

Update your model to this

```
public class ReportRealm: Object {
    @Persisted var remarkTypes: RealmSwift.List<RemarkTypeRealm>
}
```

Comment: I tried it but sorry to say but its not working same error. JYI I am not using swiftUI.

Comment: @user861715 When I copy and paste your code into a project, and add RealmSwift as in this answer, it works perfectly, so the issue is unrelated to the code in the question. I suggest clarifying your question by adding what version of Realm you're using as well as including your PodFile (if you are using CocoaPods), the cocoapods version and the XCode version. Also, please update your question with your current, updated code. The RealmSwift suggestion is not specific to SwiftUI, just in general

Comment: even my code was working perfectly since last one hour its started giving me this error. I am using SPM. Realm -10.32.2 realmDatabase 12.11.0

Comment: @user861715 Clean your project and rebuild as the code in the question is perfect with the addition of `RealmSwift.List`

Comment: did all possible things but still same issue persist

Comment: @user861715 Again, the question hasn't been updated with your new code and the code in the question works so the issue is not the code in the question. We are happy to help but need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to do that. Please update the question with your current code and a duplicatable example.